# SQL Server not releasing memory after query executes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, memory-management

I think I have a basic question here that many might have encountered. When I run a query in SQL Server it will load in memory all the data it needs for query execution (for example, if there is a join then it would load the necessary data from those two tables) but when the query finishes executing the memory consumed by SQL Server is not released.

I noticed this because a few days back I was analyzing a query that takes up a lot of `tempdb` space. When I used to run the query it would (by the end of execution) consume upto 25 GB of RAM. This 25 GB RAM would not be released unless I restarted the `MSSQLSERVER` service.

How do you guys do SQL Server memory management? This is clearly an issue right?

I would also like to hear if you do something specific to clear the memory used up by a single query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version are you using? This is a known problem up to SQL Server 2008 R2. I am not sure about 2012. I will provide an answer shortly...

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for your response. I am using 2008. Haven't checked this with 2012 though.

Comment: "This is clearly an issue right?" - no. And it's not a "problem" as Killercam phrases it. SQL Server is *designed* to grab memory and keep hold of it, unless the OS signals that its running short. Which is better in the long run - SQL Server processes each query, incurring any/all I/O costs of loading data into memory, but then neatly throws all of that data out again, or it keeps it hanging around in case future queries will benefit from the data already having been loaded?

Comment: Agreed. But in many scenarios I know for sure that the query won't be used again. I am looking to release memory in such cases. Thanks for your response.

Comment: The point is, this is what the server is *designed* to do. It grabs memory from the OS when it needs more, but then *it* starts managing that memory, deciding what to put in there, etc. And unless the OS signals low memory, it will not give it back.

Comment: Definitely agree. But what do I do if I do want to release memory programatically?

Comment: Well, it sounds like you already know how to force it to release memory - "unless I restarted the MSSQLSERVER service.". If you need help controlling a service programatically, a search on the web or here should find plenty of answers.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right. the server is this way. However, it _is_ a problem. SQL Server is advertised not only as a Transact based system, but also for use with desktop applications etc. This behaviour is fine for stand-alone servers but is a total design fault for applications running SQL Server as a backend database as it cannot be switched off (not sure about 2012). The only way I have found to restrict the memory consumption is to restrict the _Maximum Server Memory_. Note, you cannot release memory programmatically (not without service restart), only restrict it.

Comment: @Killercam - indeed - and the express edition is more limited in its use of memory. Since the OP says that their server has used 25GB, I think we can safely assume that they're not using express edition, and are therefore using one of the editions *intended* for server use.

Comment: @Killercam Well what's the issue with setting maximum server memory to a low value then if you effectively want to disable the buffer cache and have all data read from disc?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Express edition is/was not _explicitly_ release for non-server use, so I don't get your point. Express is merely a cut-down free edition that can be used for anything upto a point. I have a large desktop application that uses SQL Server as a 'back-end' service (for all sorts of stuff), and this uses Enterprise as we need more than a 10GB storage facility and certainly more than 1GB RAM. I am not sure what point you are making with the above.

Comment: I'd say that it's good idea to set both maximum and minimum server memory to the same value. When the engine is started it will occupy it's space and will not interfere with other processes. Nevertheless - here is a good reading on the subject -http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/

Comment: @Killercam - You are paying for an Enterprise Edition Licence and not running it on a server dedicated to just SQL Server?

Comment: @MartinSmith there is no major issue with restricting the memory this way. However, SQL Server gobbles up this memory for a reason (optimisation most probably), so restricting the amount of RAM will impact on performance. Having run tests on the performance hit after a significant reduction in the available RAM (8GB to 5GB), there is a small reduction in performance which of course is hard to quantify. Nevertheless, if this memory release was performed by the server itself we could have our cake and eat it.

Comment: @MartinSmith I have it avalible to me, so yes. We reccoment our clients use Standard or if they can get away with it (through the licence terms, Developer). My point above was not that I am using a version that is totally excessive for my needs, but that I _can_ use this as a back end for a web-based desktop app etc. Express is not the only version for use with desktop applications. Of course our version recommendation is dependent of the client requirements and indeed sometimes (most times) Express is enough.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

SQL Server is indeed designed to request as much RAM as possible which will not be released unless this memory is explicitly required by the operating system. I think the best approach is to limit the amount of RAM the server can use which will allow the OS to have a set amount of resources to use no-matter-what. To set this [How to configure memory options using SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx):

> Use the two server memory options, **min server memory** and **max server memory**, to reconfigure the amount of memory (in megabytes) managed by the SQL Server Memory Manager for an instance of SQL Server.
>
> 1. In Object Explorer, right-click a server and select **Properties**.
> 2. Click the **Memory** node.
> 3. Under **Server Memory Options**, enter the amount that you want for **Minimum server memory** and **Maximum server memory**.

You can also do it in T-SQL using the following commands (example):

```
exec sp_configure 'max server memory', 1024
reconfigure
```

To restrict the consumption to 1GB.

*Note: the above is not going to limit all aspects of SQL Server to that amount of memory. This only controls the buffer pool and the execution plan cache. Things like CLR, Full Text, the actual memory used by the SQL Server .exe files, SQL Agent, extended stored procedures, etc. aren't controlled by this setting. However these other things typically don't need all that much memory, it's the buffer pool and the execution plan cache which need the bulk of the memory.*

I hope this helps.

Comment: So there is no option to release memory used by a query right?

Comment: No. You would have to restart the service to force the release. The only way to restrict the consumption is as above. I have not started work with 2012 and this is something that may have been addressed (although I doubt it, as SQL Server is mainly used on a server based transact basis, and as the discussion above rightly established - here this behaviour is not an issue). If you are running the SQL service from an application, perhaps you could force the release of memory by using OS resources temporarily - however, I would not recommend this and have not attempted it...

Comment: I am facing a similar issue.. however once the SQL server memory usage reaches to its peak.. the newer queries got timeout error and there is no way except restarting mssql server. What could be wrong here? And how to fix it?

Comment: @Krunal - Were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 6):

I too faced same issue mentioned above.
But running below query in releasing the RAM memory but in less than 5 hour the RAM memory is getting occupied. So again i have to forcefully free the RAM memory.

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N’show advanced options’, N’1' RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXEC sys.sp_configure N’max server memory (MB)’, N’2048'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXEC sys.sp_configure N’show advanced options’, N’0' RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

Then run following:

2.

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N’show advanced options’, N’1' RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXEC sys.sp_configure N’max server memory (MB)’, N’6144'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXEC sys.sp_configure N’show advanced options’, N’0' RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to force SQL Server to free memory . 
However you can limit memory usage.

```
sp_configure 'max server memory', <memory_size MB>
reconfigure
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but figured i'd add my two cents. Mostly a riff on what was in the above answer using dsql to automatically roll back to the previous value after shrinking the memory amount. It's ugly, but it works.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..##globaltemp') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##globaltemp
END

SELECT TOP 1 value
INTO ##globaltemp
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE NAME LIKE '%server memory%'
ORDER BY NAME
OPTION (RECOMPILE);

EXEC sys.sp_configure N'max server memory (MB)'
    , N'1024'
GO

RECONFIGURE
WITH OVERRIDE
GO

DECLARE @dsql AS VARCHAR(20)

SELECT @dsql = cast(value AS NVARCHAR(20))
FROM ##globaltemp

EXEC sys.sp_configure N'max server memory (MB)'
    , @dsql
GO

RECONFIGURE
WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```