# How do you force SQL Server to release memory?

Tags: sql-server, windows, memory

> What's a good way of checking how much (actual) memory is currently
>   being used vs. how much is SQL Server allocated to itself?

I've been resorting to **memory_utilization_‌​percentage** but that doesn't seem to change after running the following to release memory.

```
SELECT  [Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_MB] = ( physical_memory_in_use_kb / 1024 ) ,
        [Memory_utilization_percentage] = memory_utilization_percentage 
FROM    sys.dm_os_process_memory;

DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('ALL')
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

SELECT  [Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_MB] = ( physical_memory_in_use_kb / 1024 ) ,
        [Memory_utilization_percentage] = memory_utilization_percentage 
FROM    sys.dm_os_process_memory;
```

A solution is to drop **max server memory** for the SQL Server and increase it again to force SQL Server to release unused but allocated memory. However an issue with this approach is that we cannot be sure how far to reduce **max server memory**, hence run the risk of killing SQL Server. This is why it's important to understand how much SQL Server is 'actually' using before reducing the value for **max server memory**.

Comment: The DBCC FREE calls are not designed to release memory back to the operating system, they merely mark pages related to their function as available. Once the server has allocated memory it keeps it, there is no reason for it to perform an expensive reorganisation and flush, the max memory option is the exception to this.  The real question is perhaps *why* it is you need to do this?

Comment: In case of active-active instances, SQL Server Instances will sometimes hold on to more memory than needed and it will constraint other instances that need them desperately. Is there a better way to address this other than have less instances per node and increase physical memory?

Comment: 1) This question belongs on DBA. 2) Don't do this. Tell SQL Server how much memory it is allowed to use, and it will generally use as much as it feels it needs to, up to that limit... Generally this will be the size of the whole database plus some, unless the database is bigger than the memory limit. If you don't want it to do this then you need to set the limit using the `max server memory` setting.

Comment: 1) Okay, will keep it in mind next time I post unless there is a way to move this question that you can help with? 2) DB size is definitely much larger than memory. You're right by stating that limit max server memory should resolve the issue but remember that we are talking about active-active cluster. Which means any instance can be hosted on any node. This makes it tough to allocate a specific amount of max server memory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The modified script below worked for me. I needed to temporarily release a bunch of RAM held by SQLServer so that we could run some other one-off processes on the same server. It temporarily releases SQL's reserved mem space while still allowing it to gobble the mem back up as needed.

I added a built-in wait to let SQLServer actually release the mem before bumping it back to the original level.  Obviously adjust the values as needed to suit your needs.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
/*** Drop the max down to 64GB temporarily ***/
sp_configure 'max server memory', 65536;  --64GB
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
/**** Wait a couple minutes to let SQLServer to naturally release the RAM..... ****/
WAITFOR DELAY '00:02:00'; 
GO
/** now bump it back up to "lots of RAM"! ****/
sp_configure 'max server memory', 215040;    --210 GB
GO  
RECONFIGURE;    
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server always assumes it is the primary application running.  It is not designed to share resources.  It will always take all the available memory and it will only release it for the operating system unless you throttle with 'max server memory'.

By design, Sql Server does not play well with others.

This sqlskills article recommends a baseline for throttling followed by monitoring and raising the throttle as needed:

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/how-much-memory-does-my-sql-server-actually-need/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for how to release the allocated memory. However, for our purposes we were able to figure out, how to allow active-active clusters to run safely. We've decided to set **minimum server memory** to ~2GB. This is helpful because no matter how much max memory an instance decides to use, it will never run other instances out of memory. So again, this solves our purpose but it still doesn't answer the question of how much memory is actually being used, how low can we drop the max server memory, etc...

Answer (score -1):

You have to set 'Max server memory' to some value between 1-2 GB. This range is safe in most cases. It may take a time to release the memory after executing below:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'max server memory', 1024;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

That setting allows to clear the pool, compile memory, all the caches, clr memory, etc.

The minimum value for 'max server memory' is 128 MB, but it's not recommended as SQL Server may not start in certain configurations. If it happens, use "-f" switch to force SQL start with minimal configuration, then change the value to the original one.

Comment: Thank you! However, is there a way to figure out the lowest number I should drop the 'max sever memory' rather than assuming 1-2GB is safe?

Comment: I don't think so as it depends on many parameters and configurations, that's why there is no option to clear it safely to the minimum value. Even MS set 128 MB is minimum, but they don't recommend it. Why do you need to release it? Do you run anything else on the server that consumes a lot of memory?

Comment: Servers run on an  active-active cluster, which means that any instance can run on either of the node at a given time. If instance A has allocated more memory than it needs at the time, instance B might not have enough to allocate to itself or just has less memory to work with. To avoid this, we want to manually release memory from instance A. Best way to release memory is to drop max memory and increase it again. To drop, we need to know how far to drop without affecting ongoing processes.

Answer (score -1):

This post is solved in the following link, please check the format:

[SQL Server not releasing memory after query executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291047/sql-server-not-releasing-memory-after-query-executes)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not. As I've mentioned in multiple comments, we want to release memory, not limit the max size, as this is an active-active cluster.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think SQL Server releases memory unless the operating system actively requests it. If there is a case of other processes requesting more memory and if there is none at all, SQL Server will release the unused memory on its own. Rather than trying to flush the unusued memory, I'd probably go with limiting the SQL's maximum allowed memory.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO  

RECONFIGURE
GO  

sp_configure 'max server memory', 512; --or some other value
GO  

RECONFIGURE
GO
```

For further info, you could check this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Just in case you are in an emergency situation and if you can have a small downtime, just restart your SQL service. It's just a few seconds to restart and do the job very well. Right click on your server name and click Restart.

Comment: Correct, resetting could release memory but that's really difficult to do in any production environment. A better solution would be to find kill active tasks that are using temp tables, in my opinion.